# Safe migration to EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been migrating my project from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 LTS and also update all nuget packages and following all this process I have saw that a lot of my Rest API endpoints stop working properly because of some issues with EF and DB.

Related to this article [Breaking changes included in EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) right now we have tons of breaking changes which we must fix immediately (we can't just left it as it is) to successfully migrate to .net core 3.1 and EF 3.0.

The question is, how to do a safe migration to EF Core 3.0 and how to find all places where need to fix LINQ queries?

Comment: The real change is that client-side evaluation is off by default (thank goodness!!!!). It only existed as a stop-gap measure as EF Core 1.0 couldn't even perform a `Group By`. EF Core 2.2 *already* emitted warnings every time client-side configuration was used, but most likely they weren't logged. You can configure an EF Core 2.2 DbContext to throw instead, as shown [here](https://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/ef-core-client-side-eval)

Comment: You can add `optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w =>w.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));` in your contexts, resolve the problems before migration, then migrate to EF Core 3.1

Comment: Testing, testing testing..... Of course you could move your queries into methods that are easier to test in isolation.

Comment: Of course, I need to do testing for all queries but I wondering if there an options to use something like a static analyzer to show me all places where I need to update my LINQ queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query pipeline was completely rewritten for EF Core 3.0, so technically there were many breaking changes.

In practice though, it comes down to a few that should be checked. Those are marked with a `high` impact. You can ignore the one about EF Core 3.0 and .NET Standard 2.1, because EF Core 3.1 was made compatible again with .NET Standard 2.0.

In most cases it comes down to only one breaking change with an actual impact:

[LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

This is the important one. Use `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` to explicitly switch to client-evaluation from that point in the query, or split your queries manually, where you use a lot of `Include()` calls that can lead to a [cartesian explosion](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/cartesian-explosion-problem-in-3-1/).

You could also wait for EF Core 5 (or use the latest preview now), that adds the feature of [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#single-and-split-queries), which is an improved version of what EF Core prior to 3.0 would do, that can explicitly be enabled for a query.